# fetch products by category and manage them independently react redux

Tags: wordpress, reactjs, redux, categories

I am creating bookstore app using wp-rest API and react and I am using redux as my state management library, In the app books have different category and I want to browse categories independently, but since redux have single store when calling state.concat() it concatenates different category products with each other what can I do to treat different category products independently

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask for pointers on posting a question and getting good responses.

Answer (score 0):

Just update your redux selector to nest the books into their category.

```
books
|
|_categories
  |
  |_"science fiction"
    |
    |_[books]
```

Comment: @kangroo Thank you for your response, can you make a little bit clear

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your problem correctly, then here are two ways you should be able to handle this:

1. Use multiple reducers, one for each genre, and then call combineReducers in your root reducer. So if you had a reducer for each genre, like "scienceFiction" and "Fantasy", then when you used the root reducer, your state would have sub-objects, one for each reducer. See this for [reference](http://redux.js.org/docs/api/combineReducers.html)
2. Set your state to have multiple sub-objects / sub-arrays for each genre in your single reducer. The problem people usually run into with this is that since the state object has nested objects, how do you create a new object with just the portion of state you need to updated (immatability practices). You can use either a library like immutable.js to address this, or if you just want to use plain javascript data structures, then you can use the [update function](https://github.com/kolodny/immutability-helper), recommended in the [react docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/update.html).